# I am getting error in my first RestAPI program

Tags: maven, rest-assured

This is the POM.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>new_Demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>new_Demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.9.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The java code is like:

```java
package new_Demo;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
public class RestAPI_Basics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        restAssured.BaseURI="https://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

I am getting error in 'io' in the second line of the code. Even I am getting error on `restAssured` as well. But while hovering the mouse on `restAssured`, I am not getting the suggestion for importing `io.restassured`. Why? Please find the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You have imported `RestAssured` as a library, but you have not instantiated it into a variable. You probably need to do something like `RestAssured restAssured = new RestAssured();` before setting the base URI. Have you read the documentation for this lib?

Comment: Remove this configuration part `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and follow the conventions.. locate the productive code into `src/main/java` and the tests should be located into `src/test/java`...